# Data lost during SPI communication with Polling mechanism

Tags: c, driver, signal-processing, spi

I am coding the communication between 2 DSPs through SPI. The start code is quite simple, DSP-1 is sending and DSP-2 is receiving (Of course, DSP-1 also receives but I don't care so far, vice versa for DSP-2)

That works fine. One thousand 16bit data were sent and received correctly.

However, when I add an random delay in DSP-1(master) side, I found DSP-2 begin to lost some data. It is confusing me that I didn't change anything at DSP-2 side for receiving and I am polling quite often.

So anyidea why the delay on sender's side might affect the receiver? (I double checked the DSP1 did send correct sequence.)

And I am thinking to convert to interrupt mechanism, will that solve this kind of issue for all?

my DSP2's polling code is:

```
for(;;)  //my main program for receving
{
  spi_xmit(data);  //For sending, not care so far

  while(SpiaRegs.SPIFFRX.bit.RXFFST == 0) {} //polling

  while(SpiaRegs.SPIFFRX.bit.RXFFST != 0) 
  {
    rdata[seq] = SpiaRegs.SPIRXBUF;
    seq++;
  } 

  if(seq>1000) break;
  }
```

Comment: the SPI bus cannot send and receive at the same time.  So move the call to spi_xmit(data); out of the recv loop.

Comment: when DPS-2 rxffst becomes 0 due to a delay in the DPS-1, if the DSP-2 tries to xmit (as it does in your loop) then there is a conflict in the SPI bus clock value and in the SPI bus data value.  There is a definite change in mode of the DPS-2 device setup between xmit and recv.  This is (most likely) what is causing the corrupted/lost data.

Comment: @user3629249 What "spi_xmit" does is to assign TX buf like "SpiaRegs.SPITXBUF=data", As I read from the specification, the SPI slave is mainly driven by the master (DSP1 in my case), and as SPI is working with the "shift register", it does the Send and Receive at the same time? isn't that true? But I'll try to comment out the spi_xmit to see if it is going well. THanks so much.

Comment: @user3629249 Just tried to comment out the spi_xmit and I still encounter the same kind of errors